# How to not Count Spaces in Search Box?

Tags: javascript, php, html, spaces

I've got a search box and works quite good actually. What it does is that you type something and if it already exists, it shows you the topic. If not, it sends you to page that you can open this topic. When you type "ABC" or "A BC", it's okay but when you try to type "AB" and then try to search, it gives you an error that you need to type at least 3 characters, which is good. But it can be easly done like ("a space space" - counts 3). You may open topics with spaces, sure, but don't want that spaces to be counted. Such as, (hello world) It should be counted as 10 characters, not 11. How to exclude spaces to be counted as characters?

Here is my search box's javascript file which I probably need to edit:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function formatText(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi');
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
 Field.value += '[' + tag + '/]';
}
</script>
```

To be honest, I don't really know how to adapt these suggested lines to my js codes to get it working properly.

```js
var myString = getElementById("input").value;
var withoutSpace = myString.replace(/ /g,"");
var length = withoutSpace.length;
```

Comment: That didn't work out for me, sadly.

Comment: thats not a very helpful description of the problem.

Comment: When I add the specified codes, didn't just do anything. Nothing happened. No errors or anything. So didn't know what to say.